# Need an Ant example to delete the duplicate line from a file. <uniqfilter/> is not working

Tags: ant

Need a ant script to remove the duplicate lines from a file
       -->  is not working

```
        <copy file="${logfile}" tofile="C:/workspace/oracletest/servers.txt" overwrite="yes" >
         <filterchain>
           <tokenfilter delimoutput="\n">
                    <containsregex pattern="(JB|ws)" flags="i"/>
                 <stringtokenizer/> 
                 <!--<uniqfilter/>--> 
           </tokenfilter>
        </filterchain>
        </copy>
      </target>
```

Answer (score 3):

The [doc](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/ant/ant-1.8.2/org/apache/tools/ant/filters/UniqFilter.html) seems to suggest, that you have to use a sortfilter, prior to the uniqfilter:

```
   <filterchain>
       <tokenfilter delimoutput="\n">
                <containsregex pattern="(JB|ws)" flags="i"/>
             <stringtokenizer/> 
       </tokenfilter>
       <sortfilter />
       <uniqfilter/>
    </filterchain>
```

Comment: build.xml:33: Class org.apache.tools.ant.filters.TokenFilter doesn't support the nested "sortfilter" element.

Comment: @Madhu sortfilter is not inside tokenfilter, but AFTER the tokenfilter